# Is there a way to use a variable in multiple files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im working on a discord.js bot, and I have a var in on my code for one command, but the other command relies on that. It used to be all on one file so there was no problem, but recently I made a command handler and now the var is in a different file, and its broken. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use `module.exports` to export the variable from your file.

```
// File A
const fooVariable = 'foo';
module.exports = { varToExport: fooVariable };

// File B
const fooVariable = require('./fileA').varToExport;
```

## Note

For more info check the [Node.js documentation on modules.](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

Comment: im using _var_ not _const_, is there a problem?

Comment: You can use _var_ too. But if your variable is going to be modified, you should consider using a _service_ to manage it. Otherwise you're good to go

Answer (score 0):

To export a variable, use:

```
export let varname;
```

And to import it from another file:

```
import varname from './path_to_the_file';
```

I wish it helps you. :)

Comment: It saddly dosnt work,
as I get the following error:
`export var mentionedChannel;
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)`

Comment: export const x = value;

Comment: also try to use it in strict mode, When I searched I found this way, and didn't find another ways, I am sorry if it doesn't work.

Comment: if it all doesn't work, try to move the data to a json file and then get it with node.js I think it's much easier.

Comment: what if I use _var_ instead of _cons_

Comment: You can use let, it's the same, but var runs on javascript version ES5, and let on ES6, in the docs I found just let and const, but I think you can use it.

Comment: Is it good to you? or that it gives you error? because I can't test it right now.

Comment: no, btw iis there a better way to comunicate, u have discord?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'global' key word:
`global.varName = 10`